# Transform height of child div when hover on parent div

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I would like to `transform` the `height` of my `.bar` to `3px` when hovering `.wrapper`. I know I have to use `transition` and `transform`, but I have no idea how to `transform` my child `div` by hovering his parent. At the moment, I `transform` just my parent `div` (it's clear why). How to `transform` `height` of my child by hovering my parent `div` (should be a bar coming up/down on the bottom of `.wrapper`)? Note that **the parent div should not transform** his dimensions, just the child!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  /*ON HOVER WRAPPER TRANSFORM HEIGHT OF BAR TO 3px*/
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.bar:hover {}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the child selector `.wrapper:hover>.bar`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: height 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover>.bar {
  height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, works thanks. I've edited your answer, because the parent div should not transform, just the child div. So I removed the transform from the .wrapper:hover. I will mark it as correct answer, cheers mate.

Comment: Welcome. You should remove the `.wrapper` transform code from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this CSS selector `>` to do that,

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}


/*.wrapper:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  cursor: pointer;
}*/

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover > .bar {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MrBuggy You can use this css selector > as said to select child element or even you can remove that sign > and just keep that white space between them to select child element i.e. .wrapper:hover  .bar  or .wrapper:hover > .bar